# Merge php array based on two unique values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to do a pretty odd array merge between multidimensional arrays.  Take the following two arrays `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` as examples.

I'd like to merge the arrays into `arrayThree`, which will show arrays items that are unique if **both** `number` and `letter` combined are unique.  It'll merge the values from one array with another and if the value isn't present, then it'll provide an empty string. (see `arrayThree` for what I mean)

Any ideas?

```
$arrayOne = array(
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'a', 'qcol' => 'tennis'),
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'b', 'qcol' => 'soccer'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'a', 'qcol' => 'basketball'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'b', 'qcol' => 'football'),
        array('number' => 3, 'letter' => 'a', 'qcol' => 'bowling'),
        array('number' => 3, 'letter' => 'b', 'qcol' => 'rugby')
    );

$arrayTwo = array(
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'a', 'rval' => 'bus'),
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'car'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'a', 'rval' => 'truck'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'plane'),
        array('number' => 4, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'boat')
    );
```

would merge into:

```
$arrayThree = array(
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'a', 'rval' => 'bus', 'qcol' => 'tennis'),
        array('number' => 1, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'car', 'qcol' => 'soccer'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'a', 'rval' => 'truck', 'qcol' => 'basketball'),
        array('number' => 2, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'plane', 'qcol' => 'football'),
        array('number' => 3, 'letter' => 'a', 'rval' => '', 'qcol' => 'bowling'),
        array('number' => 3, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => '', 'qcol' => 'rugby'),
        array('number' => 4, 'letter' => 'b', 'rval' => 'boat', 'qcol' => '')
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arrayThree = array();

foreach ($arrayOne as $i) {
    $arrayThree[$i['number'] . $i['letter']] = $i + array('rval' => null);
}
foreach ($arrayTwo as $i) {
    $key = $i['number'] . $i['letter'];
    if (isset($arrayThree[$key])) {
        $arrayThree[$key]['rval'] = $i['rval'];
    } else {
        $arrayThree[$key] = $i + array('qcol' => null);
    }
}

$arrayThree = array_values($arrayThree);
```