# How to merge 2 arrays in one with unique values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this

```
array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => Big Black Gay
        [searches] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => Men Seeking Men Personals
        [searches] => 1
    )
)
```

Another array like this

```
   array (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => Men Seeking Men Personals
        [clicks] => 1
    )
   )
```

How can I merge above two arrays without using any looping? Any php functionality is available for this? I need this kind of an out put

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => Big Black Gay
        [searches] => 1
        [clicks] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [search_terms] => Men Seeking Men Personals
        [searches] => 1
        [clicks] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: Weird structure. You want to use a value as a key. You should reconsider your data structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670062/merge-php-array-based-on-two-unique-values check this example

Comment: why you dont wany to use loop.. ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
var_dump(array_merge($array_one,$array_two));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$data = array(
        0 => array(
                'search_terms' => 'Big Black Gay',
                'searches' => 1
        ),
        1 => array(
                'search_terms' => 'Men Seeking Men Personals',
                'searches' => 1
        )
);

$combine = array(
        0 => Array(
                'search_terms' => 'Men Seeking Men Personals',
                'clicks' => 1
        )
);

foreach ( $data as &$item ) {
    foreach ( $combine as $new ) {
        if ($item['search_terms'] == $new['search_terms'])
            $item['clicks'] = $new['clicks'];
    }

    if (! isset($item['clicks']))
        $item['clicks'] = 0;
}

print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [search_terms] => Big Black Gay
            [searches] => 1
            [clicks] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [search_terms] => Men Seeking Men Personals
            [searches] => 1
            [clicks] => 1
        )

)
```